# ping works but tracert reaches the max hop

Tags: route

I have 4 guests in my VMware host, all of them work as expected; but if I use tracert to find out the route they take to reach the external site, all of them will reach the max 30 hops after the first hop is the gateway:

```
[root@cdsw ~]# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=9.51 ms

[root@cdsw ~]# /usr/bin/traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (192.168.122.2)  0.118 ms  0.080 ms  0.062 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Can anyone enlighten me why and how can I get the full route?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You would need to tell us what the gateway device make and model is (such as a Cisco ASA) and share its sanitized config before we could answer. Without that, it's just guessing.

Comment: Thanks. No such thing (Cisco) , this is a VMWare environment.

Comment: What is your gateway (router), you use to reach the internet? You have to terminate onto something acting as a router. What is 192.168.122.2? What's beyond it (the next device in the path to the internet?

Comment: Thanks, this is a small LAN built with VMWare on my desktop, there is no extra hardware like physical router or switch here. The entire LAN is conifgured with VMWare.

Comment: Ahh.  I see.  In that case, this is actually off topic completely on this site. This is only for corporate and enterprise network engineering questions, and questions about host configurations are off limits.  You can try asking on [Super User](https://superuser.com) instead.

Comment: Thank you, will do later. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of traceroute and different ICMP types. In contrast to *NIX traceroute, which uses UDP, Windows tracert uses ICMP.

So ICMP echo-request / echo-reply types are allowed (you can ping) but it looks like other types are blocked, this may include time to "live exceed which" is used by traceroute.

Comment: You can't make that assumption. It could just be that their gateway doesn't decrement TTL (like many firewalls do by default), which then prevents traceroute from working. That's why I said they need to provide more information before we can answer - everything (like your "answer") is just guessing.